# Bending a Flexible Strap on a Flexible Arm (simple-deform Modifier)

Tags: modeling, animation

I am pretty new to modeling and blender. I am trying to animate a strap that clasps together and also bends along with the arm, similar to a wristwatch strap. I have tried using the bending modifier alongside an [add-on](https://blender.community/c/today/x92z/?sorting=hot) which has worked fairly well except here.

As you can see in the image below, the highlighted vectors are the "straps" which will basically bend to overlap. These straps are connected to the larger "arm". This arm will bend along the profile as I said similar to a wristwatch band. I also added a snippet of what I am attempting and what happens, basically one strap is able to bend correctly, the other one would rotate, I even tried making it a separate object. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]
[image]
[image]

edit: I got an update but I still have some unanswered questions. I was able to correct the straps by "unblinking" the two objects (since the short strap was a separate object).
[image]

now I'm at a different impasse, bending the arm. I am not sure how to keep the transform without jumbling it up. If I were the parent and keep transform it would get all jumbled again.
[image]

Comment: Subdivide the straps on their width and parent to a chain of bones?

Comment: Again, bones are probably the best solution here, have you tried?